# Copy values to another greater column on known cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula, array-formulas

I'am new in 'complex' things with excel, I cant find what I look for. I tried things with index,match,row.

The marks ("x") need to be replaced with text1 till text5. The 
quantity of the texts (column B) can variate but they are always equal to 
quantity of the marks ("x") in column A. The Value of "x" and "FALSE" doesnt matter. The order of the marks in column A can change.

```
 columnA       | columnB      | ColumnC (result)
   "FALSE"     |    "text1"   | "FALSE"
   "FALSE"     |    "text2"   | "FALSE"
   x           |    "text3"   | "text1"
   x           |    "text4"   | "text2"
   x           |    "text5"   | "text3"
   "FALSE"     |              | "FALSE"
   x           |              | "text4"
   "FALSE"     |              | "FALSE"
   x           |              | "text5"
```

Is is possible to do with excel formula or with vba?

Thank you,

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: _Is is possible to do with excel formula or with vba?_ Probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in C1 and copy down.  This is assuming you have no header row(s)

```
=IF(A1<>"x",A1,INDEX(B:B,COUNTIF($A$1:A1,"x")))
```

[image: POC]

#### UPDATE for header rows

```
=IF(A1<>"x",A1,INDEX(B:B,COUNTIF($A$5:A5,"x")+4))

or

=IF(A1<>"x",A1,INDEX(B:B,COUNTIF($A$5:A5,"x")+ROW($A$4))
'where A4 is a cell in the last row of your header row.
```

Place the above in row 5 and copy down as required.

Comment: Actually I have 4 header rows, and it doesnt work in that what. Your solution only works without headerrows. I deleted them for that part (I will copy the results to another column with headerrows. Thank you! :)

Comment: @JorenV either add +4 after the countif or +row($A$4) where A4 is a cell in the last row of your header row.